# Inferior performance of Tensorflow compared to sklearn

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn

I'm comparing the performance of Tensorflow with sklearn on two datasets:

- A [toy dataset](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_digits.html#sklearn.datasets.load_digits) in sklearn
- [MNIST](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/) dataset

Here is my code (Python):

```
from __future__ import print_function

    # Import MNIST data
    from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
    mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=True)

    import tensorflow as tf

    from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
    import numpy as np

    # digits = load_digits()
    # data = digits.data
    # labels = digits.target

    # convert to binary labels
    # y = np.zeros((labels.shape[0],10))
    # y[np.arange(labels.shape[0]),labels] = 1

    x_train = mnist.train.images
    y_train = mnist.train.labels
    x_test = mnist.test.images
    y_test = mnist.test.labels
    n_train = mnist.train.images.shape[0]

    # import pdb;pdb.set_trace()

    # Parameters
    learning_rate = 1e-3
    lambda_val = 1e-5
    training_epochs = 30
    batch_size = 200
    display_step = 1

    # Network Parameters
    n_hidden_1 = 300 # 1st layer number of neurons
    n_input = x_train.shape[1] # MNIST data input (img shape: 28*28)
    n_classes = 10 # MNIST total classes (0-9 digits)

    # tf Graph input
    X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_input])
    Y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_classes])

    # Store layers weight & bias
    weights = {
        'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1])),
        'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_classes]))
    }
    biases = {
        'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1])),
        'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
    }


    # Create model
    def multilayer_perceptron(x):
        # Hidden fully connected layer with 256 neurons
        layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
        # Activation
        layer_1_relu = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)
        # Output fully connected layer with a neuron for each class
        out_layer = tf.matmul(layer_1_relu, weights['out']) + biases['out']
        return out_layer

    # Construct model
    logits = multilayer_perceptron(X)

    # Define loss and optimizer
    loss_op = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=Y)) + lambda_val*tf.nn.l2_loss(weights['h1']) + lambda_val*tf.nn.l2_loss(weights['out'])
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss_op)

    # Test model
    pred = tf.nn.softmax(logits)  # Apply softmax to logits
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(Y, 1))
    # Calculate accuracy
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
    # Initializing the variables
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init)

        # Training cycle
        for epoch in range(training_epochs):
            avg_cost = 0.
            total_batch = int(n_train/batch_size)
            # Loop over all batches
            ptr = 0
            for i in range(total_batch):
                next_ptr = ptr + batch_size
                if next_ptr > len(x_train):
                    next_ptr = len(x_train)
                batch_x, batch_y = x_train[ptr:next_ptr],y_train[ptr:next_ptr]
                ptr += batch_size
                # Run optimization op (backprop) and cost op (to get loss value)
                _, c = sess.run([train_op, loss_op], feed_dict={X: batch_x,
                                                                Y: batch_y})
                # Compute average loss
                avg_cost += c / total_batch
            # Display logs per epoch step
            if epoch % display_step == 0:
                print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch+1), "cost={:.9f}".format(avg_cost))
        print("Optimization Finished!")
        print("Accuracy on training set: ", accuracy.eval({X:x_train,Y:y_train}))
        print("Accuracy on testing set:", accuracy.eval({X: x_test, Y: y_test}))

    print("Experimenting sklearn...")
    # now experiment with sklearn
    from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
    import numpy as np
    from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
    import time

    # use MLP 
    t_start = time.time()
    print('fitting MLP...')
    clf = MLPClassifier(solver='adam', alpha=1e-5, hidden_layer_sizes=(300,),max_iter=training_epochs)
    clf.fit(x_train,y_train)
    print('fitted MLP in {:.2f} seconds'.format(time.time() - t_start))
    print('predicting...')
    labels_predicted = clf.predict(x_test)
    print('accuracy: {:.2f} %'.format(np.mean(np.argmax(y_test,axis=1) == np.argmax(labels_predicted,axis=1)) * 100))
```

The code is adapted from a [github repository](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/multilayer_perceptron.py). For this testing, I'm using a traditional neural network (MLP) with only one hidden layer of size 300.
Following is the result for the both datasets:

- sklearn digits: ~83% (tensorflow), ~90% (sklearn)
- MNIST: ~94% (tensorflow), ~97% (sklearn)

I'm using the same model for both libraries. All the parameters (number of hidden layers, number of hidden units, learning_rate, l2 regularization constant, number of training epochs, batch size) and optimization algorithms are the same (Adam optimizer, beta parameters for Adam optimizer, no momentum, etc).
I wonder if sklearn has done a magic implementation over tensorflow? Can anyone help answer?
Thank you very much.

Comment: That's not really a scientific evaluation (random-seed variance?) and it seems you ignored initialization, where sklearn follows Glorot et. al.

Comment: While I uderstand that I should use a random seed constant, I've run the experiments many times and the accuracy obtained by tensorflow code never better than that of sklearn. What do you mean by "follows Glorot et. al."? Is it a better way to initialize weights?

Comment: Read sklearn's code! Weight-init is as important as everything else. Any good survey-paper will talk about this. And as always in non-convex optimization: there is no best (we are doing heuristic-based optimization after all in some way). Often init-method A works, but sometimes B will be superior. Of course this depends on architecture, data and even optimize-algs. (unrelated, but [here are keras' init-functions](https://keras.io/initializers/) for a small overview of popular ones)

Comment: @sascha Using Xavier initialization greatly improves my result. Thanks a lot.

Comment: In addition to accuracy difference, my comparison shows a big gap among them in learning time. It takes more than twenty minutes in tf.

Comment: @lenhhoxung, Does Using Xavier initialization completely explain your gap?

Comment: @keramat Yes, for these two mentioned datasets, Xavier initialization does the trick. However, in other datasets, using Xavier initialization does not always guarantee the best performance. Sometimes, normal random initialization produces better performance even though it often converges slower than Xavier initialization.